# Does not find my CSS file in my Chrome browser, even if my path is right in the href

Tags: java, html, css

## I got 404 to my CSS file.

#### Code line between the head tag in the indexPage.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/index.css" type="text/css">
```

#### I tried in the href attribute:

- /static/index.css
- ../static/index.css
- resource/static/index.css
- http://localhost:2011/src/main/resources/static/index.css

> Except this: resource/static/index.css, my IDE said it's good, it's seeing the index.css file.

The indexPage.html is sitting on this URL: http://localhost:2011/

> My file structure:

- src

  - main

    - java
    - resources

      - static

        - index.css
      - templates

        - indexPage.html

This is a Spring project, with Tyhmeleaf

Comment: What is the file path to indexPage.html? What is the URL to indexPage.html? Path to the CSS will be relative to the URL and what the browser navigates to. What is the navigable URL of the CSS file?

Comment: Thanks for your file structure. Can you navigate to the css file? What’s that path? For example if it is http://localhost:2011/resources/static/index.css the path on index.html is “/resources/static/index.css”. The browser doesn’t know your file system, it only knows what it can access thru the browser.

Comment: I tried :<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/static/index.css" type="text/css">, but not working, and even my IDE don't like it, so then I tried: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.css" type="text/css">, which is okey for my INtelli J, but still got the same 404... Anyway thanks @neatlysliced